# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.utils.POJO[]` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json

How to convert this json to pojo but its throwing exception.Is this correct way to Date field?
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.utils.POJO[]` out of START_OBJECT token.

```
 {
        "rentals": [{
            "product": "12345",
            "startDate": "2020-08-31T19:59:59-0400",
            "AmountPaid": 100.0,
            "endDate": "2020-06-02T03:25:06-0400"
            
        }, {
            "product": "6789",
            "startDate": "2020-09-09T00:00:00-0400",
            "AmountPaid": 100.0,
            "endDate": "2020-06-02T02:41:23-0400"
            
        }]
    }






    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
            POJO [] result = mapper.readValue(json, POJO [].class); 
             mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

    public class POJO {
        
        private String product;
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-0400")
        private Date startDate;
        private String AmountPaid;
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-0400")
        private Date endDate;
    }
```

Comment: JSON text starts with `{`, which means the root is an object (hence `START_OBJECT` token) with a single field named `rentals`. The `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` feature is not what you're looking for, `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` is.

Comment: How to remove rentals root while reading json array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a root object.

```java
class ROOT {
    public POJO [] rentals;
}

class POJO {
    public String product;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-0400")
    public Date startDate;
    public String AmountPaid;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-0400")
    public Date endDate;
}
```

*Test*

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ROOT result = mapper.readValue(new File("test.json"), ROOT.class);
for (POJO rental : result.rentals) {
    System.out.println("product=" + rental.product +
                     ", startDate=" + rental.startDate +
                     ", AmountPaid=" + rental.AmountPaid +
                     ", endDate=" + rental.endDate);
}
```

*Output*

```
product=12345, startDate=Mon Aug 31 15:59:59 EDT 2020, AmountPaid=100.0, endDate=Mon Jun 01 23:25:06 EDT 2020
product=6789, startDate=Tue Sep 08 20:00:00 EDT 2020, AmountPaid=100.0, endDate=Mon Jun 01 22:41:23 EDT 2020
```